# how to get entered URL value in php?

Tags: php

here i am try to get the Entered URL value .....and i have to print that url....so give me suggestions....

Comment: in web browser..like http://www.google.com

Comment: This isn't a we-do-it-for-you site. What have you tried? Are you working with form input or just trying to get the current URL?

Comment: @cory i am try to get entered URL value...like if we write in webbrowser www.google.com then i want to fetch this url and print it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Determining the current url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867278/php-determining-the-current-url)

Comment: @ravi: you're only going to be able to capture that information from within a PHP application that you are working in, not another site like google.com. Can you describe the whole process?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Also try this to see some other useful information you can get:

```
<?php print_r($_SERVER); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to Get the Current Page URL](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php).

Answer (score 0):

The [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) array will contain all the information you need about the URL of the page being requested.  You may have to join a few values to get a complete URL, but it will have the host, the file, the URI, etc.

Comment: Surely this will give you the request that reached the web server, which is not necessarily the same as what the user entered into the browser (if for example there is URL rewriting going on, or the site has been forwarded to another site. I would like to find the URL that the browser thinks it is fetching, because this will affect the location fetched for any relative links in the HTML. Does the browser send this, in any header or anywhere else? If not then it seems to require some Javascript in the web page.