# Twig templates engine: get current url

Tags: php, twig

How can I get the current URL from a Twig template?

I am using Twig with PHP, without any other framework.

Comment: Why not pass in the current URL as a template variable? Or you could write a template tag that outputs the URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Finding the current URL**

The current URL is supplied by your web server and written to the `$_SERVER` super-global. Run this small script, `<?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SERVER);`, through your server and root around to find the value(s) you are looking for.

Related questions on this subject:

- [getting current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216172/getting-current-url)
- [PHP Determining the current url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867278/php-determining-the-current-url)
- [How to get URL of current page in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283327/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-in-php)

[The PHP manual describes the nature of the available `$_SERVER` values here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

**Getting the URL in TWIG**

After you have the URL, you need to pass it as a template variable when calling `render(...)` on the Twig template instance. For example, you might code this.

```
$current_url = // figure out what the current url is

// pass the current URL as a variable to the template
echo $template->render(array('current_url' => $current_url));
```

To use the variable in the template, you use the `{{ variable_name }}` syntax.

- [Developer's basic Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#basics)
- [Twig designer documentation for using variables](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables).

Comment: I wonder if there is any internal tool (variable ot method) to get URL from Twig?

Comment: You might find some code already written for the purpose, but retrieving the current URL is not within the scope of a template engine, so I highly doubt Twig has anything built in. I certainly couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 28):

The following works in Silex and most certainly in Symfony2 as they share the Request class (I did not test though) :

```
{{ app.request.getRequestUri() }}
```

Comment: `{{ app.request.requestUri }}`

Comment: It's deprecated, one should not use it. https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/issues/1257#issuecomment-141058724

Answer (score 4):

Go http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html

or : `{{ app.request.getUri() }}` for full Uri.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping best practice in mind, at this time you should use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack`.

See http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack.

> As of Symfony 2.4, the best practice is to never inject the request service, but to inject the request_stack service instead [...]

So in a Silex application it could be achieved with :

```
app.request_stack.getCurrentRequest.getUri
```

Answer (score 0):

Here something I found to make it generic with the sliex Framework.
I guess my solution is not perfect but it's get the job done.

in your PHP code add this code :

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
// add the current url to the app object.
$app['current_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Then in  your Twig template you can do

```
{{ app.current_url }}
```

Let me know what is the botom line of this method.