# how to: If homepage, do X TWIG PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, twig

I am trying to add a p tag to the footer if the page is the home page,
I am using spicycp, which uses .twig files.

I have tried a number of php if statements, but alas, to no avail:

```
 <p class="kktag">Digital Marketing by <a href="http://kingkong.com.au/" target="_blank">King Kong</a>
</p>
{% endif %} 
</p>
```

and

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == 'https://lfsigns.com.au/') 
{
   <p class="kktag">Digital Marketing by <a href="http://kingkong.com.au/" target="_blank">King Kong</a>
</p>
}
else
{
   <p class="kktag">Digital Marketing by King Kong</p>
}
```

and

```
{% if is_front %}
  <p class="kktag">Digital Marketing by <a href="http://kingkong.com.au/" target="_blank">King Kong1</a> </p>
{% endif %}
```

and

```
{% if entry.id == 4 %}
<p class="kktag">Digital Marketing by <a href="http://kingkong.com.au/" target="_blank">King Kong</a>
</p>
{% endif %} 
</p>
```

and

```
{% if template == 'index' %}
<p class="kktag">Digital Marketing by <a href="http://kingkong.com.au/" target="_blank">King Kong</a>
</p>
 {% endif %}
```

and

```
{% if is_front_page %} 
   <p> do something </p> 
{% else %} 
   <p> do something else. </p>
{% endif %}
```

But none of these seem to work, any ideas/suggestions/advice would very much appreciated,

Thanks everyone

Comment: Found a [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339370/twig-templates-engine-get-current-url) for passing the `$_SERVER` super global array to Twig.

Also, check out [Twig's docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables) for more info re: embedding variables in your template.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current URL from the Request object. [More details (Symfony docs)](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/templating/app_variable.html).

```
{% if app.request.uri == 'https://lfsigns.com.au/' %}
    <p class="kktag">Digital Marketing by <a href="http://kingkong.com.au/" target="_blank">King Kong1</a> </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank for your help Rhono (coolest name i've read on stack in a long time)
However, the condition is never true, i have modified the code to 

  `{% if app.request.uri == 'lfsigns.com.au/' %}
    <p class="kktag">Digital Marketing by <a href="http://kingkong.com.au/" target="_blank">King Kong</a> </p>
    {% else %}
    <p class="kktag">Digital Marketing by King Kong </p>
{% endif %}`

And the else statement is always true.

I have tried different variations of the address, lfsigns.com.au, https://lfsigns.com.au/, /, but no such luck,

Any ideas?

Thanks Rhonos!

Comment: @Khadesa, Ah, sorry I left off the front. By the by, you can test what `app.request.uri` contains using `{{ app.request.uri }}`. In any case, I've updated my answer and thanks :)

Comment: Hi Rhono, Thanks again for your help, but i'm afraid it still doesn't become 'true',
When you say `{{ app.request.uri }}`, do you mean i can print that in firebug console, which would allow me to see the correct url? How might i print this? Thanks again man :]

Comment: I just realized your question isn't tagged Symfony. Please disregard my answer.