# Timber how to implement get_current_url wp

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

Ive been using Wordpress for more than a year now. But I was stuck with the implementation of Timber twig framework get the current URL. I tried these codes below codes but no luck,.

```
{{ site.url.current }}
{{ app.request.getRequestUri() }}
```

[Twig templates engine: get current url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339370/twig-templates-engine-get-current-url)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
URLHelper::get_current_url()
```

Doc: https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-urlhelper/#get_current_url

So, you should be able to feed this as a variable into your template.

Or if you want to get a step further and [extend Timber's Twig](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/extending-timber/#adding-functionality-to-twig) i.e. creating a filter or function like:

```
$twig->addFilter(new \Twig_SimpleFilter('is_current_url', function ($link) {
    return (URLHelper::get_current_url() == $link) ? true : false;
}));
```

Which should bring things down to:

```
{{ 'http://example.org/2015/08/my-blog-post' | is_current_url }}
```

BTW: Internally, [get_current_url()](https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/master/lib/URLHelper.php) returns: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`/`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` + `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

Comment: Thanks, @wp78de I am expecting a condition like this. 

{% if(URLHelper::get_current_url() == 'example.com/custom/') %}
        true
    {% else %}
        false
    {% endif %}

Answer (score 3):

Adding *['current_url']* in functions.php under *add_to_context* function worked for me:

```
    public function add_to_context($context)
{
    // $context['foo']   = 'bar';
    $context['current_url'] = Timber\URLHelper::get_current_url();
    $context['site']  = $this;
    return $context;
}
```

You then will be able to use it globally in your twig templates:

```
 <pre>
  Current Url:  {{ dump(current_url) }}
</pre>
```